# parsing dates pandas but incorrect format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

pandas dataframe here need to parse date column

```
    date    total
3   Mar-06  1.8
4   Apr-06  1.7
```

have tried `earning['date'] = earning.date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b-%y'))`

which I thought was the correct format but does not seem to be so, can anyone help out?

Comment: Are there any trailing or leading whitespaces?

Comment: Yea check for spaces as mentioned above, and you can `pd.to_datetime(earning.date, format='%b-%y')` instead of `apply`

Comment: there were trailing whitespaces, thank you , did an apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ','')) then pd datetimed

Answer (score 0):

```
earning.date = earning.date.apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''))
pd.to_datetime(earning.date, format='%b-%y')
```

done

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wiser to use `strip()` which strips any white spaces in your strings. This can be generalised in case the size of white spaces vary from string to string:

```
earning.date = earning.date.str.strip()
pd.to_datetime(earning.date, format='%b-%y')
```